# How to disable MMS using APNs

Tags: sms, mms

Is it sufficient to simply clear (leave as blank) the MMSC, MMS proxy, and MMS protocol in an APN to disable MMS messaging completely?

As mentioned [here](https://tamingthedroid.com/what-apn-settings-mean) these are the three fields related to sending/receiving MMS.

I believe there is a setting in the stock messaging app to disable **receiving** MMS but my issue is sending.

(Stock Android Noughat 7.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable MMS

> Under your phones network settings you will see a section called
>   “access point names” or “apn’s”. You will see either one or two apn’s
>   listed. If you have two, the second one will be the MMS control. If
>   you only have one the MMS control will be down the bottom of the apn
>   settings. Just highlight the apn and choose “edit”.
>
> Look for:
>
> **MMSC** - http://mmsc.mms.o2.co.uk:8002
>
> **MMS Proxy** - 82.132.254.1
>
> **MMS Port** – 8080
>
> and insert a * or # at the beginning of each line.

If you're not on O2 then the details will be different in these three fields - or lines as phrased above, but this won't make any difference.